# Image Rows in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

Using constraints in a `ConstraintLayout`, I have created a layout as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_photo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/create_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_photo"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/share_button"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_share"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_photo"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/create_button"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_share"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My problem is that lower `ImageButtons` are not shown whenever height of image in `ImageView` is more than its width. If we hardcode a height (some kind of sufficient) on `ConstraintLayout` then buttons can get some height depending on the height of `ImageView`. I believe that the problem is when `View Bounds` are adjusted for `ImageView.` How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 1):

**wrap_content** only asks the widget to measure itself, but won't limit its expansion against eventual constraints

add following attribute to your **ImageView** which is used when parent constraint layout set to **wrap_content** then there will be height measuring problem so overcome that

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```

and also set **ImageView** height to 0dp

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_photo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo"
            />
```

for information same approach we can use in width problem
just replace width to 0dp and following property

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent this situation, you need to define **percent** or **(dp) value**.

1 - You can use **maxWidth / maxHeight** on ConstraintLayout like

```
 <ImageView
        ...
        android:maxHeight="192dp"
        />
```

2 - Also you can use **Guideline** like

```
<Guideline
       id="guideLineMaxHeightOfImage"
       guideLinePercent="0.4"
       orientation="horizontal"
       >
```

**ImageView**

```
<ImageView
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideLineMaxHeightOfImage"
        />
```